# Uniquely Identifying a mobile device

Tags: mobile-website, imei

I am designing a jsp web page for mobile web. I need to uniquely identify the user device (say: IMEI,or any other Unique id) such that i can identify them when they login again. Pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a web app, your bet bet would be to generate a unique id on the server, and store it in a cookie on the client browser.

Comment: its not a web app. its a web page. And this cookie should not be destroyed when the user clears his cookies..?

Comment: In that case you are asking for the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a cookie?

You could generate a unique id and generate a cookie as well as store that value in a table. You could restrict the generation to mobile devices.

What would be the reasoning to identify at a mobile level though?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. but what if the user clear his cache,cookies in his device? Then i will not be able to identify the user, the next time he logins...